# Why select min from table is slow on partitioning key?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a huge table (**update:** the table has over 1G rows) partitioned by a date column. And there is an index also partitioned by the column.

```
create table T (a int, b date, c int, d.... primary key (a, b)) on psdate(b) 
-- distinct count of b is around 300 only.
create index I on T (c, d) include (e, f, ....) on psdate(b)
```

However, it's slow and expensive to run the following

```
select min(b), max(b) from T
```

The execution plan shows it will do an index scan on I for all the partitions. Shouldn't it return the result instantly?

BTW, it seems the query `select e from T where a = ....` is also sort of expensive. Should I create some non-partitioned indexes? Is it ok not to partition the huge index?

Comment: Are there any additional indexes? Can you post the execution plan? Also, make sure you read this article, it tries to explain the performance problems with partitioning: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/partitioned-tables,-indexes-and-execution-plans-a-cautionary-tale/

Comment: `The execution plan shows it will do an index scan on I for all the partitions` it will need to scan at least the first partition fully. But if that is empty it would need to scan the next one fully. This pattern is not supported by the current query optimizer.

Comment: @dean No, no additional index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first question should be: why is your table partitioned? Are you using partitioning to load data into an empty partition and then switch it in? Or are you using partitioning to manage a sliding-window by quickly aging off data that has just fallen outside of the 30 day or 12 month range, for example? If neither of these, then quite possibly the table shouldn't be partitioned to begin with. Table partitioning is not designed to increase query performance (at least not according to the team that wrote that feature) and probably won't help with it until you start reaching 1 billion rows.

Regarding your `select min(b) from T` query and related question of:

> The execution plan shows it will do an index scan on I for all the
>   partitions. Shouldn't it return the result instantly?

No, it won't return instantly because partitioning requires the partition key to be used as a predicate (i.e. in the WHERE clause or as a JOIN condition) so it can do partition-elimination. Also consider that you are looking for the MIN(Date) and if the partition function has ranges that include more than 1 DATE value, then even if the optimizer narrowed down the specific partition rather quickly, it would still need to scan the entire partition because you don't have an index defined on that DATE field; partitioning divides the data, it does not index the data.

So, the first thing to consider is:

- Unpartition the table (seriously, if you are using partitioning only to improve query performance and are not even close to 1 billion rows, then you shouldn't be using partitioning, and anything you do to "fix" this issue will just be a bad decision used to cover up a prior bad decision)

Regarding the `min(b)` query, start with one of these as you will need an index for the sort required by MIN / MAX operations:

- Try creating a partitioned index on just `b`
- Create a non-partitioned index on `b` (as you had asked about, though this might have a drawback if you do SWITCH partitions in and out as that might require non-partitioned indexes to be dropped and re-added)

Additionally, you might do even better by trying one of the following techniques as you really do need to have the partition key as a predicate:

- If you have an easy means of looping through the distinct partition ranges, you can cycle through them doing, inserting the MIN() value into a table variable from `SELECT MIN(b) FROM T WHERE b = @PartitionRangeValue`. I wrote an article on the technique here: [Improving Performance of Cross-Partition Queries](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Partitioning/69898/) (requires free registration).
- Use the technique described here, by Itzik Ben-Gan: [MAX and MIN Aggregates Against Partitioned Tables](http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/max-and-min-aggregates-against-partitioned-tables)

**Alternative Solution to Consider**:
Given that you have about 300 distinct values for the DATE field across the 1 billion+ rows, is to store the distinct values in another table. This is really simple if the DATE field is never updated and rows are not deleted because the distinct values would at most increase as opposed to possibly not existing anymore. You can create the table for the distinct values, initially populate it via one-time script, and then have an AFTER INSERT trigger on the `T` table that checks the distinct value table to see if the incoming rows have any DATE values that are not yet in the distinct value table, and if so, then insert them. This would not only be super-fast to get your MIN / MAX values of `b`, but it would be 3 bytes per each of 300 rows for 900 total bytes. On the other hand, adding an index on just `b`, assuming your PK is CLUSTERED, would be at least 7 bytes (3 bytes for DATE field, 4 bytes for INT field) per each of the 1 billion rows for a total of 7 GB. And that 7 GB index needs to be maintained, and it takes a lot longer and a lot more tran log to do maintenance operations on 7 GB than it does for 900 bytes :-D. If the DATE values can be updated or rows in `T` can be deleted then maintaining the distinct row table is a little trickier, but not too much and still a lot smaller and faster to query.

Comment: The table has over 1G rows. That's why it's partitioned. Although I don't do swtich in/out or sliding window yet. It's partitioned because it has too many rows now.

Comment: @dc7a9163d9: 1G? is that 1 gazillion? ;-). Just kidding. Glad to hear that you do have a truly large table. I phrased my answer the way that I did because too many people use partitioning in the hopes of improving query performance for a far smaller set of rows. In many/most cases that ends up hurting them instead of helping so I needed to be clear not just for you, but for everyone reading this. It sounds like you need the partitioned index just on `b` to start with. Please let me know how that works out.

Comment: I will try it when I get a chance. However there are only about 300 distinct `b`.

Comment: @dc7a9163d9: How often do you get new values for `b`? Is this INSERT only or are there UPDATEs to this DATE field? If the distinct values are only being added to, then you can handle the `MIN(b)` separately from improving how the optimizer handles queries against this partitioned table. For example, you could have a separate table of distinct values and an INSERT trigger on `T` that adds to the distinct table if the new value is not in `T`. It is a little trickier if `T` can be UPDATEd or DELETEd such that a distinct value ceases to exist. Or I can just update my answer to include this ;-).

Comment: The "creating a partitioned index on just b" helps. The way mentioned in the "MAX and MIN Aggregates Against Partitioned Tables[http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Partitioning/69898/]" doesn't work - it basically still scan all the partitions of the index.

Comment: @dc7a9163d9: Glad I could help. Which article did you mean? You gave the title of one but the URL of the other. Just curious. I will update my answer to be clearer about the two types of queries: the MIN/MAX would need the index regardless. But the 2nd query you show might still benefit from at least the CROSS APPLY technique from the Ben-Gan article on sqlmag.com.

Comment: The link in "Use the technique described here, by Itzik Ben-Gan: MAX and MIN Aggregates Against Partitioned Tables" doesn't work. It still scan the index `I` and is slow. `select  min(A.pmn) as mn
from sys.partitions as P cross apply ( select min(b) as pmn from T where $PARTITION.pfMonth(b) = P.partition_number ) as A
where P.object_id = object_id('T') and P.index_id = indexproperty(object_id('T'), 'I', 'IndexID')`

Comment: @dc7a9163d9: that's fine. I updated my answer to clarify that the index is probably necessary as a first step. Now that you have created it, it might be interesting to see if you are able to get even better performance with the CROSS APPLY technique.

Comment: Yes, the cross apply partition one is much better. But both the queries returns the result instantly so it doesn't matter any more. Given the complexity of the cross apply, I will go for the simple one.

Answer (score 1):

First, let me say that partitioning was never about performance.

This excellent article by Paul White does a great job explainig why all the partitions are scanned, mush better than I would:

http://web.archive.org/web/20180422160838/http://sqlblog.com:80/blogs/paul_white/archive/2012/09/12/why-doesn-t-partition-elimination-work.aspx

It also offer some good advice about how to tell SQL Server to behave as you wanted.